# AWS SES support for singapore

Tags: amazon-web-services

My instance is in singapore and according to documentation of SES it is not available in singapore region. So how can I use the ses service. I want to use it using AWS SDK for nodejs.

also is it required that my application should be running at HTTPS ??

Answer (score 1):

In your SDK, connect to the region where [SES is available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html) - make sure the email address is verified in that region - and send mail.

No, you don't have to run HTTPS to send email by SES.

Comment: For security reasons, Amazon SES does not support HTTP requests. You must use HTTPS instead.

Comment: this is from the aws documentation

Comment: yes, https is for the SES endpoint, not for your application.

Comment: but if I will try to hit the url based on https from http protocol than it will give security error, as it does not allowed to hit https url from http

Comment: See this link: http://timstermatic.github.io/blog/2013/08/14/sending-emails-with-node-dot-js-and-amazon-ses/

Make sure you have a SES supported region in config.json

Comment: I have verified my domain successfully, now when I am trying to send mail from noreply@<mydomain>.com, it shows error